# PHP Error reading parameter type from URL

Tags: php

I want to make a simple page in PHP which read from URL a specified function with relative parameters.

My URL is like `www.mysite.com/Api.php?function=sendMail&name=AA000AA`

I get the URL using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and pass the result to a Class i wrote which has the following construct

```
public function __construct($uri = '')
```

Everything works fine until I add the parameters with ampersand where I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /data/web/Api.php:36 Stack trace: #0 /data/web/Api.php(71): ApiAction->__construct('/app/Api.php?fu...')
```

But after a check with `var_dump` i got this

```
string(43) "/Api.php?function=sendMail&name=AA000AA"
```

Which tells me is a string.
I've tried to cast it but it keep giving me the same error.

The class I'm calling has the following code

```
class ApiAction{

    protected $link;

    public function __construct($uri){
        $request = str_replace("/Api.php?", "", $uri);
        $parameters = explode("&", $request);
        $command = array();
        foreach ($parameters as $value) {
            $tmp = explode("=", $value);
            $command[$tmp[0]] = (string)$tmp[1];
        }
        $result = '';
```

}

But it get stuck in this error when I create a new instance of this class with

```
new ApiAction($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

But, as mentioned before, it work perfectly before I add parameters with ampersand, I.E.

```
www.mysite.com/Api.php?function=sendMail
```

Works without any problems

Comment: here you are mistakig why you use numeric value in string function 43 string(43) "/Api.php?function=sendMail&name=AA000AA" also in name use sting I think in this string AA000AA remove 0000 pass any other string

Comment: Its not what your passing the class its how your calling it, most likely your doing `$class->$method()` or such. Can we see line 36 of Api.php?

Comment: I'm calling the class like this new ApiAction($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

Comment: Can we see the code, the error does not match up with what your saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need encode `&` widh `%26` and use something like `parse_url` / `parse_str` to extract data.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot, will mark as correct answer